# Как использовать конструктор по умолчанию в Java?

Tags: java

Пытаюсь разобраться с конструкторами в Java и не могу сообразить, в чём принципиальное отличие этих двух моих кусков кода? Помогите, пожалуйста понять

```
class Circle {
public double x;
public double y;
public double r;

public Circle() {
   x = 0;
   y = 0;
   r = 1.0;
}
public Circle(double a, double b, double s) {
    x = a;
    y = b;
    r = s;
   }
}
```

И этого:

```
class Circle {
public double x = 0;
public double y = 0;
public double r = 1.0;

public Circle(double a, double b, double s) {
    x = a;
    y = b;
    r = s;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

1. У любого класса должен быть метод-конструктор.
2. Если он не создаётся вами, то компилятор создаёт конструктор по умолчанию без аргументов.

Отличия в приведённых классах:

1. Экземпляр первого класса можно создать двумя способами:

   ```
   //первый, без аргументов в конструкторе
   Circle c = new Circle();
   //второй с аргументами в конструкторе
   Circle c = new Circle(1.5d, 2.5d, 42.42);
   ```
2. Экземпляр же второго класса можно создать только одним способом:

   ```
   Circle c = new Circle(1.5d, 2.5d, 42.42);
   ```

Таким образом второй вариант, в отличие от первого, не позволяет создать экземпляр класса со значениями полей по умолчанию. И требует, чтобы эти значения были заданы явно, при создании экземпляра оного.

Comment: То есть например я могу сделать 2 объявления объекта класса с дефолтными полями и с полями которые мне необходимы.